# How to create a docker network with static IPs using the C# client in windows

Tags: c#, .net, docker, networking, containers

I want to set up a docker network with C# using this client: https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet.

I am using docker for windows with windows containers.

Basically all I want to do is execute this command via the C# client (executing it in cmd works fine):

```
docker network create --driver=nat --subnet=10.123.174.0/23 --gateway=10.123.174.1 my_network
```

However, somehow I do not manage to set up the network properly. I use this small piece of code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> options = new Dictionary<string, string>();
options.Add("--gateway", "10.123.174.1");
options.Add("--subnet", "10.123.174.0/23");
await _client.Networks.CreateNetworkAsync(new NetworksCreateParameters { Driver = "nat", Name = "my_network", Options = options });
```

But the network still is created with another gateway than specified, putting my options only in the network "options" array:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "my_network",
        "Id": "2bb2fabfa84518a2a11eff881c859bf324ce732c308a1d5a4d541c74870f5e70",
        "Created": "2021-03-17T14:09:01.694993+01:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "nat",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "windows",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.29.96.0/20",
                    "Gateway": "172.29.96.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "--gateway": "10.123.174.1",
            "--subnet": "10.123.174.0/23",
            "com.docker.network.windowsshim.hnsid": "3065184F-EFAF-4537-AF64-F2CD373A3261"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

I also tried to specify just "subnet" and "gateway" (without the "--") but the result was the same.
What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may see from your own example, these settings belong to IPAM.Config ([API reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/NetworkCreate)), not Options:

```yaml
"IPAM": {
    "Config": [
        {
            "Subnet": "172.29.96.0/20",
            "Gateway": "172.29.96.1"
        }
    ]
},
```

You need to create an [IPAM](https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet/blob/c0bca6142183deadb0828e47c42500eef2c78114/src/Docker.DotNet/Models/IPAM.Generated.cs#L7-L17) object and pass it to [NetworksCreateParameters.IPAM](https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet/blob/c0bca6142183deadb0828e47c42500eef2c78114/src/Docker.DotNet/Models/NetworksCreateParameters.Generated.cs#L21) argument. Here's a poor example:

```cs
Dictionary<string, string> options = new Dictionary<string, string>();
options.Add("Gateway", "10.123.174.1");
options.Add("Subnet", "10.123.174.0/23");

IList<Dictionary<string, string>> configs = new IList<Dictionary<string, string>>();
configs.Add(options);

Dictionary<string, IList<Dictionary<string, string>>> ipam = new Dictionary<string, IList<Dictionary<string, string>>>();
ipam.Add("Config", configs);

await _client.Networks.CreateNetworkAsync(new NetworksCreateParameters { Driver = "nat", Name = "my_network", IPAM = ipam });
```

Sorry, could've messed somewhere with the example as I only used C# a couple times in my life and that was years ago. Check out the [API reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/NetworkCreate) I mentioned. You can find there some examples on what data is expected.

Comment: Thanks, very obvious but somehow I didn't see it..:)